# Should I move my static resources from App Engine to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We have a web application in App Engine. I was wondering whether it is a good idea to move my static resources (i.e Images, CSS files, and JS files) out from App Engine and serve them from Google Cloud Storage.

My thinking here is two-fold:

1) We can get the advantages of a CDN with Google Cloud Storage. We can even configure metadata for each file to set expiration headers, gzip compression, etc. Also, by serving files from different domains we can have browsers download more content in parallel.

2) By off-loading some of the files from App Engine, the instance consumption is going to decrease (less requests to App Engine), so the costs will go down.

Am I right? Is this a wise move?

Thanks,

Comment: sounds like a great idea to me!

Comment: HOw will you manage deployment and version control with GCS.  At the moment when you deploy new code you are also deploying current static assets.  You can test versions and their assets.  If you tried to do this with GCS the static resource URL's would have to change each time you deploy

Comment: Correct. Basically, static resources that are going to live at GCS have a "special" naming convention. For example: image.v1.png. Every time one of these files change, we rename the file to "image.v2.png". Using this in combination with a 1 year maximum cache, we can get the maximum advantage from browser caching. Most of our deployments are 100% automated, so this process is pretty much well covered. My main concern though is that this adds complexity and I'm not sure if the gains are going to justify it.

Comment: #2 is not correct. Static files use a different architecture and dont consume instances.

Comment: Google's documentation states that static files do not consume instances, but I don't know why I have this gut feeling that somehow every request made to App Engine goes with certain processing. Maybe I'm paranoid.

At least, when I check my application logs, I can see all the requests to both static and non-static files. This might be the reason where I'm reluctant to believe that static files are totally out of the picture for GAE instances.

Anyway, does any one have anything else to add to this picture?

Comment: static resources are served by app engine infrastructure, and requests do not get routed to an instance. of course serving static resources show up in your log files - why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: This question is still valid, and the answers are fairly old, where do we stand on this now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of these make sense.

1) App Engine has a CDN-like functionality with it's edge cache.
Unfortunately, it's not well documented.  There's a few Google I/O talks on it.  Here's a start: http://eng.pulse.me/backend-tips-the-free-cdn/
There's another talk in Google I/O 2012 that you can find as well.
Your static files will be served with the edge cache if they're accessed enough, so no need to move to GCS for this.

2) It's well documented that static files don't take instances.  You've already read this, so you 'paranoia' is simply paranoia, and doesn't make sense.  It's also very easy to test by uploading a new version onto app engine, accessing a static file, and checking for a new instance in the Admin.

Comment: Thanks for your response. One more question though: right now I enabled SSL on the application, so all the content is being served through SSL. I'm wondering whether the CDN makes sense then to serve images from HTTP and not incur on the added overhead that HTTPS imposes. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Interesting question.  On GAE you pay a flat fee for SSL, so value-wise for static files, the more SSL you use, the better deal you get.  In general, you should go for SSL, the overhead is usually minimal.

Comment: The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/serving-static-files?tab=python#serving_from_your_application notes that "requests to static files are handled by the app engine infrastructure directly and do not reach the language runtime of the appliation"

Answer (score 8):

You are right, and the answer you accepted is wrong. The answer to your question from the official docs:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

> Hosting static assets for a dynamic website
>
> You can use a Google Cloud Storage to host static assets for a dynamic website hosted, for example, in Google App Engine or in Google Compute Engine. Some benefits of hosting your static assets, like images or Javascript files, in a bucket include:

- Google Cloud Storage behaves essentially like a Content Delivery Network (CDN) with no work on your part because publicly readable objects are, by default, cached in the Google Cloud Storage network.
- Bandwidth charges for accessing content will typically cost less with Google Cloud Storage.
- The load on your web servers is lessened when serving the static content from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: incorrect. appengine static files do not consume server (appengine Frontend instance) resources

Comment: @ZigMandel - Do you have a link for that, because there are two conflicting answers here, and only one of them quotes material from Google.  Thank you!

Comment: this answer is incorrect. it is quoting from google docs that refer to hosting on GCS for regular (non appengine) websites. the checked answer explains the edge cache.

Comment: @ZigMandel either this answer is correct, or this documentation is misguided. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-dynamic

Comment: @user763694 I don't think the documentation you linked to their invalidates the accepted answer. You CAN use google cloud storage, but you don't HAVE to use cloud storage. The documentation refers to potential advantages - but these don't necessarily apply. If you host static assets on app engine without using a static file handlers, it will add load to app engine, but using static handlers it appears you get it for free, which is noted at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/serving-static-files?tab=python#serving_from_your_application

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is right, here's the confirmation from [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/serving-static-files#serving_files_from_cloud_storage):

> The benefits of using Cloud Storage instead of serving directly from your app include:
>
> - Cloud Storage essentially works as a content delivery network. This does not require any special configuration because by default any publicly readable object is cached in the global Cloud Storage network.
> - Your app's load will be reduced by offloading serving static assets to Cloud Storage. Depending on how many static assets you have and the frequency of access, this can reduce the cost of running your app by a significant amount.
> - Bandwidth charges for accessing content can often be less with Cloud Storage.

Know that static files are *definitely* served using instance resources. It's true that edge cache comes into effect, but this does *not* simply remove the whole problem. Moving statics to GCS is the *right* way of doing this.

**Note, however,** that if you plan to serve your static files from GCS, you won't be able to properly map a (sub)domain to it over HTTPS (SSL) and you'll have to use a load-balancer or 3rd party CDN. In some cases this may prove to be more of a hassle. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Moving static assets to Google cloud storage is recommended and has many advantages, have a look at this:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website
and personally it improves my webapp performance and reduces load on server.