# After deploying python app on Google App Engine changes are reflected after several minutes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have an app on Google App Engine, I used to deploy my application and see the deployed files and changes instantly.

But recently I have to wait about 5 minutes to see if the files are changed.

The only thing that I suspect is that I changed the application Zone. I am not sure what was the default Zone but now I set it to us-central1-a.

How can I solve this issue? I want to see all changes instantly as before.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't select an app's *zone*, you can only select its *region*. But only once, you can't change it afterwards, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589246/change-gae-application-location.

Comment: Are those static files? If so - check if they're not by any chance cached.

Comment: @DanCornilescu How to remove catch? if you mean the cache browser, I start an incognito tab each time but the result is same.

Comment: I also meant edge-cache, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073038/should-i-move-my-static-resources-from-app-engine-to-google-cloud-storage/19085976#19085976

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for not seeing your changes instantly after deploying is that you didn't change the application version. Instances with the same version will continue serving traffic until they die off, which could take a while. If instead you bump the default version, traffic will only be routed to instances that are funning the newer version of the code.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I don't remember ever seeing a previously running instance survive a deployment and most of my deployments don't change the service versions. I'm using std env python. I noticed that as I usually check the logs right after deployment and I always see the instance startup info msg for the 1st post-deployment request...

Comment: Good question. I dug around for a few minutes and didn't find anything authoritative to point to. This is something I picked up while working on the App Engine team, but it's a been a few years now, and I may be describing how things used to work. I do know that following this advice has kept me out of trouble, except for the separate class browser caching issues. If I find something authoritative, I'll drop a comment here.

Comment: Cool. Thx. To clarify, the `ever` in my case obviously means since I started playing with GAE, which is just a bit over 2 years now ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been working with GAE for years. The changes used to reflect on the server instantly without changing the version. It sure will solve the issue if each time we remove the version on the server before deploying it, but that would be very time consuming. Specially because I deploy 100 times a day to check every change I make.